# FluentMigrator Execute

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator, serenity

I'm using Serenity Framework and FluentMigrator to interact with database.
When I try to execute a personalized query, I receive an error on `Execute.Sql`

The error is: `Execut does not exist in the current context`

This is my code

```
using FluentMigrator;

namespace MyNameSpace.Migrations.DefaultDB
{
    [Migration(20230623_172000)]
    public class DefaultDB_20230623_172000_Insert : AutoReversingMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            Execute.Sql(
              @"My query");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest asking this on https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator/issues